# Perl `*foo{THING}`, subs and parenthesis

Tags: perl

Besides the classic function call

```
sub foo { ... };
foo 1, 2, 3;
```

Perl allows to define closures

```
my $foo = sub { ... };
$foo->(1, 2, 3);
```

(In this case, lexically local)

Even though I can't find a non-hackish purpose of it, Perl also allows to do this:

```
*main::foo = sub { ... }
```

Which obtains pretty much the same effect as the first form, except that I *must* put parenthesis around the arguments:

```
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

If I don't put the parenthesis, I get the following error:

```
Number found where operator expected at - line 6, near "&main::foo 1"
    (Missing operator before  1?)
syntax error at - line 6, near "main::foo 1"
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

…and this happens also if I call it with the `&foo 1, 2, 3` syntax, making it explicit that it's about a function.

So my questions are:

- How come the parenthesis can be omitted in the first form, but not in the third?
- Is there a purpose for the third form? It seems to me a bad practice to inject a callback in a package's namespace, since it makes things implicit and not detectable.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Perhaps perl has to see function definition first and `*main::foo = sub { ... }` doesn't do that. Similarly https://eval.in/434959 also doesn't work.

Comment: Third form is sometimes useful when testing code - it could be used to stub out or substitute expensive calls. That's what `Test::MockModule` basically does. There are better ways (e.g. Dependency Injection) but sometimes you don't have that control over code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*main::foo = sub {` is evaluated at run-time, while the errors are thrown at compile time. Normal `sub` is parsed in compile time and Perl parser can then recognize its name as a bareword, but you can't still use the bareword form before the declaration:

```
foo 1;  # Number found where operator expected...
sub foo {
    say shift;
}
foo 1; # No error here.
```

You can schedule the code to compile-time by enclosing it into a BEGIN block:

```
BEGIN {
    *main::foo = sub { say shift };
}
foo 1; # No error!
```

Comment: You are right, `foo(1)` works in your code, while `foo 1` does not. Suspecting a similar reason I also tried the `&foo 1` version (i.e. tell the compiler, at compile time, that `foo` is a function). It does not work, but I guess this is just a limitation.

Any idea on the purpose of the `*main::foo = sub {...}` form?

Comment: Mostly a sideeffect of being able to do `*somepackage::somefunction = sub { ... };` to allow hooking package subs (mock/testing etc.). And `main` is a package in it's own right.

Comment: @Dacav: Playing with symbol table might be useful in some situations - generating getters/setters, mocking, etc.

Comment: Thank you guys, both for the answers and for the mocking idea! Nice indeed

Answer (score 2):

```
sub foo { ... }
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
BEGIN { *foo = sub { ... }; }
```

You can omit parens around parameters when the sub has already been declared when the sub call is compiled. In the case where you are getting an error, the call to the sub is encountered before the sub is declared (which would have happened when the assigning to `*foo` would have been executed).

- `*foo = sub { ... };` declares the sub when the statement is executed.
- `BEGIN { *foo = sub { ... }; }` declares the sub when the statement is executed, which is immediately after it is compiled.
- `sub foo { ... }` declares the sub when the statement is compiled.